# Convert the dictionary to data frame in pyspark for unicode key and list of float values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dictionary instance which has unicode (uses UTF-8) key and value as list of float values. When i run below code:

`dictDF = sc.parallelize(mapOfVectors).toDF()`

It fails with error:
Can not infer schema for type: type 'unicode' when converted RDD to DataFrame.

Can someone suggest how it can be done?

Comment: does this help? `sc.parallelize(mapOfVectors).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()`

Comment: try creating your dataframe explicitly with the schema.

Comment: Also, could try using `createDataFrame` after you make the `rdd` and define a schema if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd
dictDF = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(sc.parallelize(mapOfVectors))
```